# How to change disabled attribute of input tag on button click using Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template

I am trying to change the disabled attribute of the  tag on a button click using Angular 2. So far I can disable it once, however I would like to toggle this function back and forth.

This is my code for my HTML template.

```
<div *ngIf = "hero">
            <h2> {{hero.name}} details! </h2>
            <button (click)="goBack()">Back </button> 
            <button (click)="edit()"> Edit </button>
            <button (click)="save()">Save </button>
            <div><label> Id: </label> {{hero.id}} </div> 
             <div>
                <label> Name: </label> 
                <input [(ngModel)] = "hero.name" placeholder = "name" 
               [disabled]="change" />
            </div>

        </div>
```

This is my code from my component

```
hero: Hero; 
editOn: boolean = true; 
change: string;     
edit(): string

{

if(this.editOn)
{
    this.editOn = false;
    this.change = "abled";
    console.log("Change propery status: ", this.change);
    return this.change;

}else if (!this.editOn)
{
     this.editOn = true; 
    this.change = "disabled";
     console.log("Change propery status: ", this.change);
    return this.change;

}
```

This is the browser of what I currently have with console.logs to show my property value is changing.
[Broswer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6amow.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right hand side of the `[disabled]` directive needs to be a `boolean` value. Both `"disabled"` and `"abled"` are truthy values. Thus, it evaluates to `[disabled]="true"`

Example:

```
if(this.editOn)
{
    this.editOn = false;
    this.change = false;
    console.log("Change propery status: ", this.change);
    return this.change;

}else if (!this.editOn)
{
    this.editOn = true; 
    this.change = true;
    console.log("Change propery status: ", this.change);
    return this.change;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! This has helped a lot!

Comment: @EdwardMuldrew Glad I could help :-)